# Getting JavaScript data arrays from webpage

Tags: php, javascript

OK, so this webpage does things different. It uses text files and loads the data in JavaScript and then displays it in JavaScript. I tried using PHP methods but I can't get it.

How do I get the `S` array of player hiscores from http://queville.com/cgi-bin/forums/index.cgi?a=scores&b=Overall

Like, if you view the source, you'll see this between `<script>` `</script>` tags:

```
 S[na]="|Daminion|442776|30436|125645|90728|40835|79058|16318|15927|43700|129|0|"; na++; 
 S[na]="|superfly|442490|32398|32032|161903|93689|75086|20018|11020|15937|407|0|"; na++; 
 S[na]="|GodessCrystal|435702|46422|41721|95881|43717|105026|23324|23500|30296|25815|0|"; na++; 
 S[na]="|grandkool|432065|110849|34644|12438|7706|165145|60924|12436|23446|4477|87|"; na++;
```

I've tried using PHP's `file_get_contents` and like but it doesn't work...

Comment: What do you get when you use `file_get_contents` (and "like")?

Comment: I get blank results... try it yourself. >_<

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for me:

```
$x = file_get_contents("http://queville.com/cgi-bin/forums/index.cgi?a=scores&b=Overall");
preg_match_all("/S\[na\]=.+/", $x, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => S[na]="|popatop|7210055|1040749|495318|1691275|958880|1084535|401043|535678|163810|838767|1399|"; na++; 
    [1] => S[na]="|SusieQ|6102424|1047948|484290|934258|613093|1222478|344052|515099|109392|831814|253|"; na++;
    // lots more
)
```